# enabling pepper flash trace log in chromium on 64 bit Linux Gentoo

Tags: chromium, debug, adobe-flash

I need to have flash player trace log for my development environment.

The only one I could successfully install flash debug version on Gentoo Linux `~amd64` is by emerging chromium and downloading `flash_player_ppapi_linux_debug.x86_64.tar.gz` and unpacking it in the relevant directory.

now when I browse to `chrome://flash` I see `26.0.0.131 /usr/lib64/chromium/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`
 and when I right click on a flash content I see a `Debugger` button which shows that it's indeed the debug version of flash.

now I'm trying to enable trace output into a log file.

I have `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` and `~/mm.cfg` files with the following relevant content:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

and after starting chromium and running the flash application I don't see any log file that is being created. I tried looking at `~/.adobe` or `~/.macromedia` or `~/.config/chromium` but nothing.

any ideas ?

Comment: Please stop developing for Flash. It still exists for legacy reasons but it really should be left to die. HTML5 can most likely do anything you're trying to achieve and is actually supported and not as flawed/vulnerable.

Comment: @Ginnungagap - I'm in the middle of converting my app from flash to something else, I still need this to finish the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I needed to place `mm.cfg` inside `~/.config/chromium/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System` and now `flashlog.txt` is created inside `~/.config/chromium/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/Logs`